# Android how to generate big size image (i.e. 3200 x 3000 pixel) with actual quality

Tags: java, android

I am thinking of creating an android application that deals with big resolution image(s) for example, 3200 x 3000 pixels. Handling that size image will cause outofmemory exceptions. One way to handle this is using the sampling and scaling the image. But this will also output a low quality image (in my app preserving the actual quality is a must). So i don't want to go through this process. I am asking you guys to help me finding a way to generate a large image with actual quality. Note that, I am not interested in NDK.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

On 3.0+ devices, you can put the attribute `android:largeHeap ="true"` in you manifest. That will ensure that you have enough memory to load you image, but be aware you are still limited by the memory of the phone.

Comment: as the image size is very large, that will not help anyway. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display big images, you can use [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) to deal with just loading the part you want to show.

If you want to generate them, you could consider generating smaller tiles and saving them, and then you don't have to have all of them in memory at the same time.